# MySQL information_schema table fragmentation

Tags: mysql

I noticed that the data_free of the information_schema table in MySQL is getting huge, e.g., information_schema.PROCESSLIST.

Is it possible to resolve the fragmentation of this table?
I could not run the optimize table because it said I did not have permission to do so.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  How big is the free space now?  How many tables do you have?  How much data (GBs) is your entire dataset?

Comment: MySQL is 5.7.33.
The total DB capacity is 8 TB, of which about 6 TB is used.
The number of tables is about 150 tables.
Because of frequent updates, data_free is increasing in the tables themselves, but data_free in the information_schema is also increasing a lot.

For example
SELECT table_name, data_free FROM information_schema.tables
COLUMNS 3783262208

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_file_per_table`?  Do all the tables claim to have 3.7GB of Data_free?

Comment: I have innodb_file_per_table turned on.
Not all tables have huge data_free.
It seems that some tables in information_schema have data_free of 0.
At least the following table had the same 3783262208.

information_schema
.COLUMNS
.EVENTS
.OPTIMIZER_TRACE
.PARAMETERS
.PARTITIONS
.PLUGINS
.PROCESSLIST
.ROUTINES
.TRIGGERS
.VIEWS

Can they be released by restarting the MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

A guess...

`information_schema` is contained in a single "tablespace" with shared "data_free".  That is, it is as if you had `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`, but only for those tables.  A clue was "tables had the same 3783262208".  This is what happens with OFF -- the free space is not for any individual table, but for all of them combined.

3GB out of 6TB is insignificant; don't worry about it.  Don't bother rebooting.

On the other hand, I would worry about 6TB/8TB of disk being used.  That could make it risky to `ALTER` a large table if it has to "copy".